# Pyramid Pattern for

Tags: java

[image: click to see image]

Hi I am new to JAVA.I have been practising but got stuck at a pyramid problem.Please help how to do it.This should be the output when number of rows which the user should input=5.

I have tried myself but could only incorporate the # not the @

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
    int  i,j,k;int cnt=0;

    for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
        for(j=1;j<=x-i;j++)
        {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }

        for(k=i;k>0;k--)
        {
            if(cnt%2==0)
            System.out.print(" #  ");//even position
            else
            System.out.print(" @  ");//odd position
            cnt++;
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `for` loops to

```
  for(j=1;j<=x-i;j++)
    {
        System.out.print("   ");
    }
  for(k=i;k>0;k--)
    {
        if(cnt%2==0)
        System.out.print("#     ");//even position
        else
        System.out.print("@     ");//odd position
        cnt++;
    }
```

Output:

```
            #
         @     #
      @     #     @
   #     @     #     @
#     @     #     @     #
```

Comment: ok now you see the output shown and the generated output differ by some spaces in between can you help how to get those spaces I gonna show the output generated by the modified program

Comment: give some extra space after `#`, `@`.

Comment: sorry but adding a space disturbs the whole pattern

Comment: in first and second for loops  give some extra spaces and check it. ex 3, 5.

Comment: ok now i got it i got the ouput by adding some extra spaces thanks satya